# Function chr (asciicode) return unknown alphabet in php

Tags: php

I am using function `chr` and trying to echo between `chr(161)` and `chr(206)` (www.ascii.ca/cp874.htm)

It displays unknown alphabet

[image]

```
<?php

echo "ภาษาไทย" ;

for ($i=161 ;$i<206;$i++)
{
   echo "</BR>".chr($i)."</BR>";
}

?>
```

What should I do?

PS. File saved in utf-8

Comment: it likely has something to do with the font you are using, where it doesn't have ASCII codes 161 - 206 defined.

Comment: @Jonathan Nope, if it was a font problem, you'd typically see funny square boxes. A black question mark diamond hints at a Unicode encoding problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chr` does not output "characters" or "alphabets"; in that sense it has a very misleading name.
`chr` merely turns a decimal number into a raw byte. `chr(161)` just returns the byte `xA1`.  You're then outputting this byte to the browser. The browser now interprets this byte using an encoding; whatever encoding you specified in your HTTP `Content-Type` header or in an HTML charset `<meta>` attribute.

In your case it seems the browser is using UTF-8 to interpret the data. `xA1` by itself doesn't make any sense in UTF-8, hence you get the "broken character" character instead. Try View → Encoding → Latin-1 instead in your browser to see other random characters appear.

See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for more information on the topic of encodings.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

echo "ภาษาไทย" ;

for ($i=129 ;$i<175;$i++)
{
   echo  "<br /> ".chr(224).chr(184).chr($i)." => 224 184 $i </br>";
}

?>
```

ref : http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=3584&number=128&utf8=dec